# momentjs adding one week returns wrong res

Tags: momentjs

```
moment("20-52", "YY-ww").add(1, "week").format("YY-ww");
```

The result is `20-01` but I'd expect it to be `21-01`

Any ideas? Is this a bug or am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You must use ISO week of years (`WW`), with lowercase `ww` moment get the week of the last day of the week in question.

```js
const ue = moment("20-52", "YY-WW", true).add(1, "week").format("YY-WW");

console.log(ue);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```